# Ruby on rails 3 - Show decimals

Tags: database, ruby-on-rails-3, equation, decimal

Probably one of the simpler questions but I haven't found a solution for it. I want to show 2 decimals after making an equation of numbers coming from a database.

This is the code I have.

```
(((@best.price * @amount) + @best.retailer.profile.shippingCost)/(@best.productSize.productSize * @amount))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[number_with_precision](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper.html#method-i-number_with_precision) is your friend:

```
number = (((@best.price * @amount) + @best.retailer.profile.shippingCost)/(@best.productSize.productSize * @amount))
```

Then in your view:

```
number_with_precision(number, :precision => 2)
```

Comment: Looks like he is talking about money, so `number_to_currency` from the same module may be applicable too.

Comment: Hi, thanks but when I try these two solutions, example: I get 5.00 when it should be 5.10.

Comment: Hi, 
I added ".to_f" to @best.price and now it worked! Is that the best solution?

Comment: Yes. If all operands are of type Fixnum, the result will also be of type Fixnum. If at least one operand is a Float, the result will be a Float too. Try "1 / 2 * 3" vs "1.0 / 2 * 3" at the console.